# Circle-Packing chart with direction links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, circle-pack

I'am trying to create circle-packing chart like that 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530

But I also want to create some relation between data, to show how data binds to each other, so I need to add some code to change example above to make it like on this image: Circle chart with relational links

[image]

So the question is: is it possible to add relational between **children** in array to reach desired behavior and change `Circle-chart` layout to **Linked Circle chart layout**?

P.S. I'm new in `d3.js` so I don't have deep knowledge in this field, so It would be great if you provide me some examples how to reach that

Comment: If you're asking for tutorial, it's too broad. (have you read basic tutorials?)

Comment: actually I'm asking for solution

Comment: Generally the main question is how to draw relation arrows between specific circles using code from example of circle-packing

Answer (score 3):

I've solved my problem my problem by myself, The solution is that to draw arrows by hands without d3 layout tools, I hope it could be useful for someone:
[`Circle pack with relation arrows`](http://jsfiddle.net/OlejkaIntersog/xkn5fwxv/)